# woocommerce calculate price server-side

Tags: woocommerce

I need do sell a product whose price depends on a complex calculation over non-discrete parameters set by the customer on the product page, and also on a custom database query result.
How can i calculate the price server-side every time the customer changes parameter-values and apply that price when the customer adds to cart?

i read a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20608947/advanced-pricing-policy-in-woocommerce-is-it-possible) whose answer suggests a WC plugin, but even that plugin doesn't satisfy my needs.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Probably, you should try to use woocommerce_get_price filter

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'get_dynamically_generated_price', 10, 2);

function get_dynamically_generated_price($price, $product) {
    // ... here doing your magic with $price based on $product
    // ...

    return $price;
}
```